# ViewPager with left and right preview

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I need to set up a `ViewPager` with the following requirements:
- at any given time,  3 pages must be visible in the screen
- the center page isn't scaled and the behind pages are 60% of the center page;
- center page, must overlap a bit the behind pages.

From what I saw in other questions I've tried to do this:

```
    viewPager.setClipToPadding(false);
    int padding = (metrics.widthPixels - centerViewSize) / 2;
    viewPager.setPadding(padding, 0, padding, 0);
    viewPager.setPageMargin(-(padding / 2));
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(10);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

Doing this got me here:

[image]

This is what I was expecting. Just need to bring to front the current selected item.

I've then tried to scale the view with:

```
public static final float SCALED_SIZE = 0.6f;
    viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new PageTransformer() {
        @Override
        public void transformPage(final View page, final float position) {
            if (position < -1) {
                page.setScaleX(SCALED_SIZE);
                page.setScaleY(SCALED_SIZE);
            } else if (position <= 1) {
                float scaleFactor = Math.max(SCALED_SIZE, 1 - Math.abs(position));
                page.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
                page.setScaleY(scaleFactor);
            } else {
                page.setScaleX(SCALED_SIZE);
                page.setScaleY(SCALED_SIZE);
            }
    }});
```

But that gives me some problems.

1. The first item that should be selected is not the correct one.
2. Animation chopy.
3. At some points, there are more than 3 pages on the screen.
4. Scale is from the bottom and I would like to be from the center.

[image]

Any idea how I can solve my issues?

Answer (score 0):

use Library [UltraViewPager](https://github.com/alibaba/UltraViewPager). It have very nice effects.